# The best method of storing large excel file in database

Tags: node.js, excel

My application requires rapid fetching of excel data from file as big as `100,000` lines.

The serverside is currently `nodeJS` and the excel parsing tools are too slow and memory issues occur when I attempt to load such a big excel file into the program.

If I can somehow store the excel spreadsheet cells into a database, I can make queries to only retrieve n number of rows.

The problem is that the files that will be uploaded to the server do not have a set schema so I can't generalize a schema and push to the tables.

Any suggestions on storing `xlsx` files in database for rapid retrieval of data would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you wish to process large files in nodejs then you can use stream api.
On the other hand there are tools that allows to load excel files to sql databases.

Comment: @Kieper yes I have tried exceljs, excel, xlsx modules for node but they are all too slow. Is there any tool that provide API to load excel files to sql database?

Comment: "The problem is that the files that will be uploaded to the server do not have a set schema so I can't generalize a schema and push to the tables." Then infer a schema. If you don't have to process the columns yourself (so it's not important that the data is properly typed), use a big string type for all of them. Cobble together a `CREATE TABLE` based on the file header; add a column for the row ID and index that.